# How is the user defined aggregations different to having a table aggregated via sql/power query in import mode?

Tags: powerbi

I'm exploring the concept of aggregations in Power BI.

I understand that the auto feature is only available when the corresponding table is in direct query mode. Where as manual aggregations is supported for import as well as direct query mode.

Effectively we can write an aggregate group by SQL Query to fetch the data and load it into an aggregate table in import mode.

I'm unable to understand how this helps because since the aggregate table is in Import mode, the source database table will need to be queried at each data refresh. So what problem does aggregates solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the source database table will need to be queried at each data refresh.

But the source database table will not need to be queried for each visual render.  Visuals render for each user on load and on any change to another visual (like selecting in a slicer, or cross-highligting in a chart).  In pure DirectQuery every visual render sends a DAX query, which translates to one or more SQL queries.

SQL queries over large fact tables can require many seconds of CPU time in the source, where the same DAX can read an in-memory aggregation table in a few milliseconds.

So the problem it solves is to reduce the number of queries to the source from report users.  Typically you create aggregates that satisfy the initial views of reports and dashboards, and the most common slicers and filters used by  the reports.

Comment: But then the data refresh (for the aggregate table) will be massive (that is - read all the data from source table)? So rather than this why not just use an import mode for the table?

Comment: The aggregate table is the result of a GROUP BY query.  So if the base table has 10B rows, when you GROUP BY a handful of carefully selected columns, might have 1M or fewer rows.  And this feature is _specifically_ for scenarios where the base table is too big to import.  If you can import the base table, do.

Comment: Ok and does the aggregations even in the presence of import mode helps improve performance?

Comment: In theory it could help for very large import tables, but it's not supported "The Detail Table must use DirectQuery storage mode, not Import.".  You can still build aggregate tables in import and reference them directly in visuals or measures.